# What's the determinant of matrix B using the determinant of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The problem states:
"Let A be a square matrix of order n and detA = 6. Let matrix B be another matrix, which is the result of matrix A, after all the elements of a single row have been replaced with the elements of another row in the matrix A, multiplied by 8. What's detB equal to?"

My suggestion is that the result is -48, because first we replace two rows, which means the determinant's sign changes, so it becomes -6, and after that we multiple that row by 8, which means we have to multiply the whole determinant by 8, resulting in -48.

Is that right?

Comment: No. The elements of the replaced row and the elements of the row used for the replacement are now linearly dependent as vectors. Hence the determinant is zero. Replace does not mean "switch" rows. It means that the replaced row is "erased" and the other one is put in it's place. Once  that is done, the answer is zero. Since $0*8=0$, the final answer is also zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Take a look at one such pair of matrices. Set $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we replace the first row with $8\times$ second row to get

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 24\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, ask yourself:

- What is the determinant of $B$ (and is it $48$?)
- When is the determinant of $B$ equal to what it is in my example? (think linear dependence)
- Does the same thing happen in al matrices?

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch! That's was really quick and helpful. So I'm assuming that whenever a row is equal to another multiplied by a scalar, then the determinant of a matrix is 0 for all matrices. In fact wasn't there a rule that if two rows are the same, the  determinant is 0?

Comment: @Mr.Nicky The detedminant is $0$ if the rows are **linearly dependent**. A special case of that is if two rows are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\0&6\end{array}\right)$$

has determinant 6

now let's replace the first row by the second row multiplied by 8

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 48\\0&6\end{array}\right)$$

has determinant 0

can you see why this will always be the case?

also you may be confusing "replace" and "swap" if you swap the rows then indeed the sign changes. If you swap and multiply:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 48\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$

indeed the determinant is -48 (this is not what I would have understood from the question though)

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful! Yeah, I definitely had confused replace with swap.